# Can 風が強く also refer to disruptive behavior rather than a strong wind?

Tags: word-choice

Im reading a comic and two guys are basically being noisy af, and messing around. Their friend walks in and says 君たち...今朝は風が強かったな.

I just assumed at first hes talking about the weather, but im wondering if its possible hes referring to the two guys being noisy and just horsing around ( i.e, its very lively/ loud this morning) , as it seems a rather random thing to say that the wind is strong ( given the scenario).

Comment: これですか？ → https://syosetu.org/novel/87837/2.html　「やあ君たち、今朝は風が強かったな…　おかげで朝から女子高生のパンチラが拝めたぜ…」って・・

Comment: You should check other definitions for 風.

Comment: ＠Chocolate, @user3169, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the comic was the one @Chocolate mentioned, He's definitely talking about the weather.
But like you thought it has other meaning, the sentence itself is a bit too humble to say out loud for high school kids.
It is not that hard to guess that because of the weather, he got something he wants to share.
the case of the comic, he peeked パンチラ of his schoolmates.

So the phrase has a meaning of greeting and an introduction of the following story at the same time.

Comment: thanks man, what exactly is 拝める supposed to mean here? My dictionary gives a simple definition of "to see" but why not just use 見る then.

Comment: `拝める` is a word of `拝む` + able just like understand and understandable. and  `拝む` means to worship. `拝める` is often used as seeing something he wanted to see but didn't expect it actually happens.